# Ubuntu 12.04 unable to save all settings

Tags: ubuntu

I reinstalled Ubuntu while keeping the /home folder of my last version of Ubuntu remaining. But now I am not able to save settings any more. Every time I lock a program to the launcher, it disappeared after restarting the system. Also, I am not able to change the background image. I click the pictures in the background setting dialogue but the background never change.

What is wrong with my Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: you logged in as root user ?

Comment: I logged in as non-root user

Comment: log in as root , because the user might not be having all privileges !

Comment: But I did not need log in as root user in my previous Ubuntu and was able to save all settings. Moreover, my current account is an Administrator user. So why I am not able to customized it?

Comment: Well, maybe because I am using my previous /home folder?

Comment: may be mate ! I am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have expected, it is an issue about privilege. By executing chmod -R u+wr . in the terminal. The problem solved.